# GXT LiveGrid set default status string before and after loading the data through RPC call

Tags: gxt

I am using a liveGrid to load the data dymaically from the server.
The code is working fine. Now, I need to do a small enhancement in that, and for that I need some advice.
I need to display, a generic string like "Loading...", before the data gets populated from the server.
This can be done as following :-

LiveGridView liveView = new LiveGridView();
liveView.setEmptyText("Loading...");

Now, once the RPC call returns, I get my data, and I set the same in the live Grid and that works fine.
But when I dont get any data from the RPC call, I need to change that "Loading..." string to a new string like "No data available on the server". So, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Ajay

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution for this.
After the data is loaded, we can add a Loader.Load listner on the loader, and check the Length of the result. If it equals zero, then change the LiveGridView's emptyText value.

Thanks
Ajay